# Does "std::size_t" make sense in C++?

Tags: c++, size-t

In some code I've inherited, I see frequent use of `size_t` with the `std` namespace qualifier.  For example:

```
std::size_t n = sizeof( long );
```

It compiles and runs fine, of course.  But it seems like bad practice to me (perhaps carried over from C?).

Isn't it true that `size_t` is built into C++ and therefore in the global namespace?  Is a header file include needed to use `size_t` in C++?

Another way to ask this question is, would the following program (with *no* includes) be expected to *compile* on all C++ compilers?

```
size_t foo()
{
    return sizeof( long );
}
```

Comment: C doesn't have namespaces.

Comment: It's built into C++, when you #include <cstddef>, and is in the namespace std. See my answer below.

Comment: It's not 'another way to ask this question' - it's a different question: main returns int.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

There seems to be confusion among the stackoverflow crowd concerning this

`::size_t` is defined in the backward compatibility header `stddef.h` . It's been part of `ANSI/ISO C` and `ISO C++` since their very beginning. Every C++ implementation has to ship with `stddef.h` (compatibility) and `cstddef` where only the latter defines `std::size_t` and not necessarily `::size_t`. See Annex D of the C++ Standard.

Comment: Absolutely the best answer here.  It's based on the standard instead of a particular compiler.  It answers the original question without straying down tangents.

Comment: Another reason to not use `using namespace std`

Comment: @Darryl: To be fair, all the older answers did so too.

Comment: C++11 standard says that cstddef should define everything that stddef.h does, including ::size_t. So I see no reason to use std::size_t instead of size_t. See "18.2.2: <сstddef> The contents are the same as the Standard C library header <stddef.h>, with the following changes..." and here is nothing about absence of ::size_t.

Comment: @eugene the answer is c++03 specific. Feel free to extend itto cover C++11. One advantage is that your code stays c++03 conforming if that is one of the goals.

Comment: @EugeneShapovalov I am unconvinced by that quote:  if we go with your interpretation, then it never says that `std::size_t` should be defined! I guess that even that sentence is still meant to be taken in conjunction with [contents]/2 which says "All library entities [...] are defined within the namespace std..."

Answer (score 42):

Section 17.4.1.2 of the C++ standard, paragraph 4, states that:

"In the C++ Standard Library, however, the declarations and definitions (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.5) of the namespace std."

This includes items found in headers of the pattern *cname*, including *cstddef*, which defines size_t.

So std::size_t is in fact correct.

Answer (score 13):

You can get `size_t` in the global namespace by including, for example, `<stddef.h>` instead of `<cstddef>`.  I can't see any obvious benefit, and the feature is deprecated.

Comment: Some explanation of the downvote would be polite. The answer is correct & on topic.

Comment: I don't know who voted you down. Your observation is very much on point to the original question.

Comment: I voted you down, mainly because there is a non-deprecated way of doing this: using-declarations, i.e. `using std::size_t`, and you didn't mention this as a better alternative. :-)

Comment: Except I think @fizzer was explaining how you *might* end up with size_t in the global namespace in your C++ program, not making a recommendation that you *do* so.

Comment: You didn't really answer the question. You answered a related question.

Answer (score 4):

size_t is not built into C++. And it is not defined by default. This one doesn't compile with GCC:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
size_t size;
}
```

That said, size_t is part of POSIX and if you use only basic things like `<cstdlib>`, you will likely end up having it defined.

You could argue that std::size_t is the C++ equivalent of size_t. As Brian pointed out, std:: is used as namespace to avoid setting global variables which don't fit everybody. It's just like std::string, which could also have been defined in the root namespace.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::size_t n = sizeof( long );
```

Actually, you haven't asked what specifically seems to be a bad practice int the above. Use of size_t, qualification with std namespace,...

As the C++ Standard says (18.1), size_t is a type defined in the standard header . I'd suggest to drop any thoughts and impressions about possible inheritance from C language. C++ is a separate and different language and it's better to consider it as such. It has its own standard library and all elements of C++ Standard Library are defined within namespace std. However, it is possible to use elements of C Standard Library in C++ program.

I'd consider including  as a dirty hack. The C++ Standard states that the content of  headers is the same or based on corresponding headers from the C Standard Library, but in number of cases, changes have been applied. In other words, it's not a direct copy & paste of C headers into C++ headers.

size_t is not a built-in type in C++. It is a type defined to specify what kind of integral type is used as a return type of sizeof() operator, because an actual return type of sizeof() is implementation defined, so the C++ Standard unifies by defining size_t.

> would the following program (with no
>   includes) be expected to compile on
>   all C++ compilers?
>
> ```
> size_t foo()
> {
>     return sizeof( long );
> }
> ```

The C++ Standard says (1.4):

*The names defined in the library have namespace scope (7.3). A C ++ translation unit (2.1) obtains access to these names by including the appropriate standard library header (16.2).*

The size_t is a name defined within std namespace, so every program that uses this name should include corresponding header,  in this case.

Next, the 3.7.3 chapter says:

*However, referring to std, std::bad_alloc, and std::size_t is ill-formed unless the name has been declared by including the appropriate header.*

Given that, program using size_t but not including  header is ill-formed.

Answer (score 3):

The GNU compiler headers contain something like

```
typedef long int __PTRDIFF_TYPE__;
typedef unsigned long int __SIZE_TYPE__;
```

Then stddef.h constains something like

```
typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;
```

And finally the cstddef file contains something like

```
#include <stddef.h>

namespace std {

  using ::ptrdiff_t;
  using ::size_t;

}
```

I think that should make it clear. As long as you include <cstddef> you can use either size_t or std::size_t because size_t was typedefed outside the std namespace and was then included. Effectively you have

```
typedef long int ptrdiff_t;
typedef unsigned long int size_t;

namespace std {

  using ::ptrdiff_t;
  using ::size_t;

}
```

Comment: So GNU defines it that way, does that mean that all compilers do? Does the standard say it must be so?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes other libraries will define their own size_t.  For example boost.  std::size_t specifies that you definitely want the c++ standard one.

size_t is a c++ standard type and it is defined within the namespace std.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know if "::size_t" or "std::size_t" (or perhaps both) are part of the language spec?

Answer (score 2):

I think the clarifications are clear enough. The `std::size_t` makes good sense in C++ and `::size_t` make (at least) good sense in C.

However a question remain. Namely whether it is safe to assume that `::size_t` and `std::size_t` are compatible?

From a pure typesafe perspective they are not necessarily identical unless it is defined somewhere that they must be identical.

I think many are using something a la:

```
----
// a.hpp 
#include <string>

void Foo( const std::string & name, size_t value );

-----
// a.cpp
#include "a.hpp"

using namespace std;

void Foo( const string & name, size_t value ) 
{
  ...
}
```

So in the header you defintely use the `::size_t` while in the source file you'll use `std::size_t`. So they must be compatible, right? Otherwise you'll get a compiler error.

/Michael S.

Comment: ::size_t doesn't make sense in C, which has no namespaces.