# Difference between size_t and std::size_t

Tags: c++, size-t

What are the differences between `size_t` and `std::size_t` in terms of where they are declared, when they should be used and any other differentiating features?

Comment: I'd be interested to know if the C++ spec links std::size_t to the C size_t type.

Comment: See similar question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237370/does-stdsize-t-make-sense-in-c)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

C's `size_t` and C++'s `std::size_t` are both same.

In C, it's defined in `<stddef.h>` and in C++, its defined in `<cstddef>` whose contents are the same as C header (see the quotation below). Its defined as **unsigned integer type** of the *result* of the **sizeof** operator.

C Standard says in §17.7/2,

> size_t which is the **unsigned integer type** of the *result* of the **sizeof** operator

And C++ Standard says (about `cstddef` header) in §18.1/3,

> The contents are the same as the Standard C library header , *with the following changes*.

So yeah, both are same; **the only difference is that C++ defines `size_t` in `std` namespace.**

Please also notice that the above line also says *"with the following changes"*  which isn't referring to `size_t`. Its rather referring to the new additions (mostly) made by C++ into the language (not present in C) which are also defined in the same header.

---

Wikipedia has very good info about range and storage size of size_t:

> **Range and storage size of size_t**
>
> The **actual** type of size_t is
>   **platform-dependent**; a **common mistake**
>   is to assume size_t is the same as
>   unsigned int, which can lead to
>   programming errors,[3][4] when moving
>   from 32 to 64-bit architecture, for
>   example.
>
> According to the 1999 ISO C
>   standard (C99), size_t is an unsigned
>   integer type of at least 16 bits.

And the rest you can read from [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_t) at wikipedia.

Comment: Thats brings to another Q, If STL already imports size_t through C (cstddef) the why it has its own another version again?

Comment: @Als: Strictly speaking, it is an error to say `size_t` without `using namespace std;` or `using std::size_t;`. However, most compilers allow it, and the Standard specifically allows them to allow it (§D.5/3).

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Surely it can't be both an error and specifically allowed in the standard? If it's in the standard, it's not an error!

Comment: @BenHymers The standard specifies what the standard headers declare, and they are not allowed to declare any other non-reserved names. The header `<cstddef>` may or may not declare `::size_t`, so you cannot rely on it being there or being absent, unless specifically including `<stddef.h>` or another header from the C library which is guaranteed to declare it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Ah, I see what you mean now! I must have gotten confused by too many "allow"s in one sentence. I still think your first comment is too strong though; as you just said, `::size_t` is present e.g in `<stddef.h>`, so you don't always need to qualify it with `std::`.

Answer (score 19):

From C++03 "17.4.3.1.4 Types":

> For each type T from the Standard C library (footnote 169), the types ::T and std::T are reserved to the implementation and, when defined, ::T shall be identical to std::T.

And footnote 169:

> These types are clock_t, div_t, FILE, fpos_t, lconv, ldiv_t, mbstate_t, ptrdiff_t, sig_atomic_t, size_t, time_t, tm, va_list, wctrans_t, wctype_t, and wint_t.

Comment: So portable code shouldn't rely on the `std::T` variants being defined?

Comment: @Mankarse: You shouldn't rely on them being defined *if* you only include the C version of the corresponding header.  If you `#include <stddef.h>` then `std::size_t` might or might not be available.  If you `#include <cstddef>` then `std::size_t` is available, but `size_t` might not be.

Comment: @Mankarse: The oposite. The C++ versions of the headers must define them in `std::` and the paragraph says that it may also define them in top-level namespace and if it does, it must define them identically in `std::` and top-level. Most compilers just include the C header and import the names to `std::`, so the symbols do end up defined in both.

Comment: Personally, I never bother with the <cxxxxx> headers or the `std::` variants of identifiers that come from the C shore. I stick with `<xxxxx.h>` for the standard C headers - it's never been a problem.  So, I'd use `<stddef.h>` and `size_t` and never give a second thought to `std::size_t`; in fact, it never crosses my mind that there is (or might be) a `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 18):

*std::size_t* is in fact *stddef.h*'s *size_t*.

*cstddef* gives the following:

```
#include <stddef.h>
namespace std 
{
  using ::ptrdiff_t;
  using ::size_t;
}
```

...effectively bringing the previous definition into the std namespace.

Comment: As Nawaz points out, it's actually the other way around. You can't include `<cstddef>` and expect to get `::size_t`, but if you include `<stddef.h>` you will get `std::size_t`.

Comment: @MSalters, I don't follow. Including `<stddef.h>` will only get you `::size_t`.

Comment: That is a bug in your implementation, then.

Comment: @MSalters, I don't quite follow. Shouldn't it be the other way round? <cstddef> comes from C++, thus should define the stuff in std::*? On the other hand, in a C header, like stddef.h, I would only expect the C type, i.e. ::size_t.

Comment: @MSalters, since C++11 that's not accurate. If you include `<cstddef>` you are guaranteed to get `std::size_t` and you might also get `::size_t` (but it's not guaranteed). If you include `<stddef.h>` you're guaranteed to get `::size_t` and you might also get `std::size_t` (but it's not guaranteed). It was different in C++03 but that was effectively unimplementable and fixed as a defect.

Comment: This answer is outright incorrect. This is an assumption about the implementation that other implementations may not adhere too. The standard specifically states that `cstddef` will define `std::size_t`, but it may or may not introduce `::size_t` (it neither requires nor prohibits it0. Even if the implementation does introduce `::size_t`, that could be done either through placing a `using ::size_t;` into `namespace std` or placing a `using std::size_t;` into the global namespace, there's no way of guaranteeing which method an implementation will do it.