# How does size_t and the __w64, time_t and __int64 work?

Tags: c++, size-t, int64

I am not a veteran in C or C++. I don't know the how`time_t` is defined and designed.
Several posts like:

- [What is ultimately a time_t typedef to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to)
- [What is size_t in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c)
- [Difference between size_t and std::size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813700/difference-between-size-t-and-stdsize-t)

But these posts only state what is `time_t` or `size_t`. It didn't state clearly how and where is time_t or size_t defined and declared.

I am using **WIN8 VS2012 Express C++**. I searched the library and found that `size_t` is defined in `crtdefs.h` instead of `cstddef`.

- Why need types like `size_t`, `time_t`? We can let `sizeof` just return `unsigned int`.
- Why C++ library does not define `size_t`?
- Can I say size_t is **NOT** a C/C++ built-in type?
- I never need to include the corresponding header file in my program to use `size_t` or `time_t`(maybe they are defined in `std` namespace).

I searched again in the library, and found `size_t` is defined as `typedef _W64 unsigned int   size_t`, and `_W64` is defined as `__w64`. Up here, I cannot search more on where is `__w64` is defined or declared.

- What is `__w64` type? It is not stated in the C++11/C99 standard.

Similarly when I searched the `time_t`, I found `__int6`. But does not know where `__int64` comes from.

Comment: `size_t` is in the standard. That's what you should be looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unsigned int vs. size\_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`__w64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s04b5w00.aspx) is a Microsoft specific extension that "enables warnings when compiling with /Wp64" - it is used to identify code that is "dangerous" if you are trying to compile it for 64-bit - for example assigning a 64-bit value to a 32-bit one. e.g.:

```
size_t s;
...
unsigned int i;

...
i = s;    // 32 bit can't take all 64 bit values - possible problem.
```

The definition of `size_t` and `time_t` are `typedef ... size_t;` and `typedef ... time_t;` - they are not "fixed" in the compiler. The standard just says they have to be there (and be suitable for the system the compiler targets). I think you'll find that `cstddef` includes `crtdefs.h` in some place or another.

The [`__int64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z.aspx) is a Microsoft compiler type. This is defined by the compiler itself. It can then be used to define other "sized types", such as `time_t` or `size_t` (with suitable `unsigned` as needed). Other compilers may not have this type, but there will be SOME way to define a 8, 16, 32 and 64-bit integer. The actual origin of `__int64` is probably before the origin of `long long`, which for a long long time (pun intended) wasn't supported by Microsoft. I believe it is now.

Comment: I think it is. `long long` *is* official as of C++11.

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ has 20+ years legacy and it is implemented now maybe on 100+ different architectures.

In fact, some of them are really different from x86. On some of them integer registers are 16 bit, while the address space and address registers are 32 bit. I have experience writing in these environments.

Yes, in this case `int/unsigned int` is 16 bits, and this makes sense, while pointer and size_t are 32 bits. On x86 this is not so, but well...

This is the answer.

> size_t is NOT a C/C++ built-in type?

The true answer is yes and no. Theoretically, you can write your own header files, like `crtdefs.h`. And write there whatever you want. The compiler most likely will work. But this is a lot of work. Nobody is doing that. Once system header files are part of compiler, then well,  `size_t` is built in....

Comment: Int is not 16 bit long, it's *at least* 16 bit long. It doesn't depend o  register size or anything, it depends only on the ABI.

Comment: Your statement is primarily wrong. The size of int depends in the decision of compiler makers. And their decision depends on reasons like the aspects of the architecture. Size of the registers is one of the primary aspects. ABI does not come out of nowhere.

Comment: No, *your* statement is primarily wrong. The size of int depends on the decisions *ABI designers* make. What they base they decision on doesn't really matter. If a compiler is following an ABI (and most are...), then the ABI defines exact sizes of integer types, EOT.