# C++ Primer Questions

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, size-t

I am currently going through the 5th edition of C++ Primer by Lahoie, Lippman and Moo and have been struggling with a few things.

Firstly, I just wanted to confirm, when using any of the `cctype` functions, I have to make sure I include the header, right? Because, initially, I forgot to include it and yet it still ran. That's really confused me.

Also, I was browsing for a different problem (which I'll get to) and found another issue haha! When using anything from `cctype`, are I supposed to write it as `std::/write using std::`, e.g. if I use the `tolower` either write `std::tolower` at every instance/write a using statement for it. This would make sense as it did say that they are "defined in the `std` namespace" but I didn't realise and have been writing it without and haven't had an issue. And I'm guessing similar for `size_t`, right?

Speaking of `size_t`, I have an issue. This is my code:

```
// Exercise Section 3.5.2., Exercise 3.30

#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t num_size = 10;
    int num[num_size] = {};

    for (size_t n = 0; n < num_size; ++n) {
        num[n] = n;
        cout << num[n] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So the code is supposed define an array of 10 `int`s and give each element the same value as its position in the array.

It runs correctly, but I am receiving an error at the `num[n]=n` part. It says `Implicit conversion loses integer precision: size_t (aka 'unsigned long') to int`.

I understand what this means, but my issue is that the book says "when we use a variable to subscript an array, we normally should define that variable to type `size_t`". I have done this and it gives this error. It does run fine but it seems like that sort of thing that can lead to errors.

P.S. In this code, like I asked above, should I have `using std::size_t`?

Comment: An individual compiler may pull in certain headers on its own.  This doesn't mean you shouldn't "do the right thing" explicitly, as an implementation detail that isn't defined in the standard is subject to change without warning.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I wasn't saying that I wasn't going to put it in David. I was just confused. Initially, I forgot to put it in and it ran. Afterwards, I realised and put it in, but wanted to make sure that you were supposed to and I wasn't getting mixed up, that's all. Thanks for the help and I'll bear that in mind!

Comment: Also, thanks Nathan for the advice. Unless I missed it, the book didn't give that. Also, to Code Apprentice, I'm using the most recent version of Xcode. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> Firstly, I just wanted to confirm, when using any of the cctype functions, I have to make sure I include the header, right?

Yes, that is right. You might get some function declarations or other declarations indirectly but that is not portable code. You should understand where the standard says a declaration is available and include that header file before using a function, a type, etc.

You asked:

> And I'm guessing similar for `size_t`, right?

Yes, you should use `std::size_t`.

There is an SO post related to the topic. Browse [Difference between size_t and std::size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813700/difference-between-size-t-and-stdsize-t).

You asked:

> In this code, like I asked above, should I have using std::size_t?

In the loop, it's OK to use `int` too. The suggestion to use `std::size_t` for indexing an array is a good suggestion but is not inviolable.

If you choose to use `size_t` for `n`, it's OK to use `static_cast` to convert it to an `int` to get rid of the compiler warning/error.

```
num[n] = static_cast<int>(n);
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. The book had yet to talk about static_cast, so I didn't know about it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

> Must I include the header even though it works without?

Yes, you must always include at least one header providing each definition / declaration you need, unless the exact prototype / type definition is guaranteed and you put it directly into your source code.

Some standard headers may include others, which might let you get away with being sloppy some of the time, but you will rue it the day you upgrade / port to a different implementation.

> I read all the declarations and definitions are "defined in the std namespace" but I didn't realise and have been writing it without and haven't had an issue. And I'm guessing similar for size_t, right?

Yes, it's the same. Due to compatibility, it is possible for the `<c...>` headers adopted by inclusion from C / Unicode to also provide their symbols in the global namespace.

> #### 17.6.1.2 Headers `[headers]`
>
> 1 Each element of the C++ standard library is declared or defined (as appropriate) in a header.175
>   2 The C++ standard library provides 55 C++ library headers, as shown in Table 14.
>   3 The facilities of the C standard Library are provided in 26 additional headers, as shown in Table 15.
>   4 Except as noted in Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D, the contents of each header cname shall be the same as that of the corresponding header name.h, as specified in the C standard library (1.2) or the C Unicode TR, as appropriate, as if by inclusion. In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace std. **It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations (7.3.3).**
>   5 Names which are defined as macros in C shall be defined as macros in the C++ standard library, even if C grants license for implementation as functions. [ Note: The names defined as macros in C include the following: assert, offsetof, setjmp, va_arg, va_end, and va_start. —end note ]
>   6 Names that are defined as functions in C shall be defined as functions in the C++ standard library.176
>   7 Identifiers that are keywords or operators in C++ shall not be defined as macros in C++ standard library headers.177
>   8 D.5, C standard library headers, describes the effects of using the name.h (C header) form in a C++ program. 178

> In my example program I used `size_t` for the array index. That works, though I get a warning. Should I have done so, and could it in general lead to errors?

Well, naturally the same about namespace `std` applies, as you guessed.

As to the rest, there's a wonderful phrase: "Good advice comes with a rationale".

The reason you should use `std::size_t` for indices is that this type a) signals to readers that it's a size or index and b) it is guaranteed to be big enough.
In your case, a lowly `int`, with its guaranteed minimum maximum of 2<sup>15</sup>-1 would have been perfectly fine.
An alternative is just casting to the proper type on assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You declare your array as

```
int num[num_size] = {};
```

This means it is an array of `int` that has `10` elements.

Then you say

```
for (size_t n = 0; n < num_size; ++n)
    num[n] = n;
```

Note that `n` is of type `size_t` aka `unsigned long`. Therefore you are putting `unsigned long` values into your `int` array, so they are being implicitly converted to `int` values.

Comment: I understood that. I was confused by why the book was telling me to do something that would give me an error, that was my concern. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NintendoMad888 Well.. it told you to use `size_t` for the type of the thing indexing the array.  But you're using the `size_t` thing for two purposes.  One in indexing the array (`[n]`), and a second time when assigning to the content of an element of the array (`= n`).  The compiler is complaining about the assignment, not the indexing.

Comment: I understand that's what it is complaining about. But the problem is, the book has stated to use `size_t` to index an array, and then the exercise question is asking me to give each element the same value as its position. So I use everything I've learnt in order to do what is asked and am given the error. I understand why it is given, I'm just unsure as to why the book is teaching in a way that would give errors.
But I guess the book does say "normally" use size_t, so I guess the best thing in this case is to not use it.

Answer (score 2):

The standard headers put a bunch of stuff in the global namespace.  Ideally they wouldn't, but they do.  Usually that's because something is really a macro rather than a typedef or function.

You can sometimes get away without including headers because some other header that you have included includes the missing one.

Answer (score 2):

> I have to make sure I include the header, right? Because, initially, I
>   forgot to include it and yet it still ran.

Some standard headers can include other headers. However it is a good idea to include a header explicitly if some declarations from the header are used in the program. It may occur such a way that in other implementations of the included headers the required header will not be included and the compiler will issue an error.

> . This would make sense as it did say that they are "defined in the
>   std namespace" but I didn't realise and have been writing it without
>   and haven't had an issue.

The C++ Standard allows compilers to place C standard functions in the global namespace. Though even in this case it is better to specify explicitly namespace std where the function will be declared in any case.

As for the last question then the elements of the array have type `int` while you assign to them values of type `size_t` The problem is that type `int` can not accomodate all values of type `size_t` and the compiler warns you about this. You could explicitly specify casting that to say the compiler that you know what you are doing.

```
num[n] = ( int )n;
```

or

```
num[n] = static_cast<int>( n );
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The book hasn't yet mentioned static_cast or ( int ) unless I missed it. I'll bare those in mind!