# Why am I getting 1, 10, 110, 1110 etc. rather than 1, 10, 100, 1000 etc.?

Tags: c++, iteration

I am a beginner with C++.

I'm trying to create a loop with `std::size_t`, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly. The variable (`i`) should start at `1` and iterate which `i <= 10000`. Each time it iterates, `i` should be multiplied by 10.

Therefore, the values should be `1`, `10`, `100`, `1000`, `10000`

However, I am getting `10`, `110`, `1110`, `11110`

```cpp
int main()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i <= 10000; i += 1)
    {
        i *= 10;
        std::cout << i << " \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The code does `i += 1` and `i *= 10`.

Comment: In addition to multiplying by 10 after each iteration of the loop you add one, so the values of `i` before each iteration are 1, 11, 111, 1111, .... Btw. the use of `size_t` does not change anything here compared to using another integral type that's sufficiently large. In this case replacing `std::size_t` with `int` or `unsigned long long` would result in the exact same output.

Comment: Try taking pen and paper, and imagine yourself being a computer and just write down values of `i` and `i *= 10` on each iteration. Do not need to do 10000 iterations, you will clearly see a point after 3.

Comment: Consider using a debugger. You will immediately see what is wrong

Comment: I agree if you had a debugger like the one in Visual Studio or even gdb you would have seen the bug in less time than it took to post a question. That is provided you know what the keys are to get the debugger to execute 1 line at a time instead of just running your program to completion. Also you would have to look at the variables at each step.

Answer (score 4):

Your loop is multiplying `i` by `10` *before* displaying `i`, so you never see `1` printed out.  And then you are also *incrementing* `i` by `1` *after* multiplying it by `10`, which you should not be doing at all in this situation.

Lets walk through the logic:

- on the 1st iteration, `i` starts at `1`, and is multiplied by `10`, so `10` is printed, then `i` is incremented by `1`.
- on the 2nd iteration, `i` is `11`, which is multiplied by `10`, so `110` is printed, then `i` is incremented by `1`.
- on the 3rd iteration, `i` is `111`, which is multiplied by `10`, so `1110` is printed, then `i` is incremented by `1`.

And so on.

To fix this, you need to get rid of `i += 1` altogether, and move `i *= 10` outside of the loop *body* and into the loop *counter*, eg:

```cpp
int main()
{
    for(std::size_t i = 1; i <= 10000; i *= 10)
    {
        std::cout << i << " \n";
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/CzDDfb)

Answer (score 2):

> the values should be 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000

Then you want something like this:

```
for (std::size_t i = 1; i <= 10000; i *= 10)
    std::cout << i << " \n";
```

Comment: While the answer is correct, it feels incomplete to me. Adding an explanation for the problem with the original code would help complete this answer.

Comment: There's already two perfectly fine explanations of the problem in the comments to the question. I merely solved the problem.

Comment: @Blindy Regarding your first comment, the nature of this site means that answers implicitly prompt for criticism.

Comment: Is it even necessary to write `std::size_t` instead of `size_t`?

Comment: Comments can vanish at any time. A good answer should be reasonably complete in this case means adding the explanation even though it's present in the comments...

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa [Difference between size_t and std::size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813700/difference-between-size-t-and-stdsize-t)

Comment: This problem is so trivial that the answer is pretty much self explanatory.

Comment: @Blindy I *am* trying to do them a favor but providing criticism. Because that is how answers are improved. Responding defensively is the disservice.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa [Is it wrong to use an upvote to balance out a downvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311406/is-it-wrong-to-use-an-upvote-to-balance-out-a-downvote)

Comment: And you seem to be offensive. I still have not, at any point, asked if you believe my answer is flawed or not, and why that would be so.

Comment: @Blindy It seems like you expect users to withhold their comments about the post unless a post author explicitly requests them. That isn't how this site works. It is irrelevant whether or not a post author has asked for feedback, comments or opinions. The whole site is structured around peer review. You can disagree with feedback, but you cannot simply dismiss it for being unprompted.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers correctly explain what your problem is, you could have figured this out without asking here on SO, if you would go through its execution step by step, using a debugger.

Here are two Stackoverflow questions about debugging on Linux and on Windows:

- [How to debug a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2590931/1593077)
- [How do you debug a C program on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19176795/1593077)

(these are about debugging C programs, but the same tools and environments can be used for debuging C++ programs as well.)

If you were to debug the program, stepping through individual commands, you would notice the sequence of changes which @RemyLebeau [describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66876908/1593077) - yourself.

Also, and for future reference - most StackOverflow users expect question askers to perform their "due diligence", making reasonable efforts to figure out their problems before asking us for a solution. Now that you know about debuggers - please use one before asking "Why does my program not do what I expected".

Comment: That is the best answer so far.

Comment: @SergeyA: Well, it was either giving this answer, or marking as a dupe of any one of the other questions about "why does my program not do what I want?"