# c++ undefined reference class constructor

Tags: c++, linker, reference, undefined

I'm trying to use a library where one of the classes has a constructor like so:

```
public:
AreaNodeIndex(size_t cacheSize);
```

I'm trying to instantiate an object of this class in my program like so:

```
size_t const cacheSize = 50000;
AreaNodeIndex areaNodeIndex(cacheSize);
```

The linker gives me the following error:

```
main.o: In function `main':
make: Leaving directory `/home/Dev/_quicktest_build'
main.cpp:(.text+0x212): undefined reference to  
osmscout::AreaNodeIndex::AreaNodeIndex(unsigned int)
```

I think I have the necessary includes and I'm linking to the library with the compiler. For example, if I try to instantiate the object without any arguments on purpose I get this error:

```
../quicktest/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../quicktest/main.cpp:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘osmscout::AreaNodeIndex::AreaNodeIndex()’
/usr/local/include/osmscout/AreaNodeIndex.h:75: note: candidates are: osmscout::AreaNodeIndex::AreaNodeIndex(size_t)
/usr/local/include/osmscout/AreaNodeIndex.h:33: note:     osmscout::AreaNodeIndex::AreaNodeIndex(const osmscout::AreaNodeIndex&)
```

So I can see the correct prototype (though here it says size_t and before it said unsigned int)...

I can use other parts of the library fine. Here are the actual source files for the class in question:

http://libosmscout.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=libosmscout/libosmscout;a=blob;f=libosmscout/include/osmscout/AreaNodeIndex.h

http://libosmscout.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=libosmscout/libosmscout;a=blob;f=libosmscout/src/osmscout/AreaNodeIndex.cpp

I'm pretty lost as to why this is happening. I feel like I've missed something obvious.

*In response to the replies:
The library gets size_t from "sys/types.h", so I don't think we're using different versions. The library was compiled on my system with the same compiler (g++, linux).
Changing the 'const' specifier location has no effect.

I am linking to the library. As I mentioned, I can use other classes from the library without issue. Here's the linking command:

g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/473/gcc/lib -o quicktest main.o    -L/home/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/473/gcc/lib -losmscout -lpthread

The library name is 'osmscout'.

kfl

Comment: Is it a dynamic library or a static one? Are you using gcc on linux, as it seems?

Comment: Can you post also the output of this command: `objdump -t libosmscout | c++filt | grep AreaNodeIndex`?

Comment: I'm the author of the library. Please contact me to solve the problem. This could possibly a problem with symbol import/export macros in the library, because of wrong compiler options for compiling your code.

Answer (score 2):

Possible cause of the problem in your case could be because of *mixing* of different  `size_t` as mentioned by @rodrigo. For consistency maybe you can include `<cstddef>` where you are using `size_t` unless your project declares it own `typedef` for `size_t`. Please refer the link below.

Please refer [Does "std::size_t" make sense in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237370/does-stdsize-t-make-sense-in-c)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is a standard type, but its equivalence is _implementation defined_, as long as it is unsigned. So the compiler has freedom to change it in different environments or with different compiler options. Not that it is wise to do that...

Comment: @rodrigo: But don't you think it will be consistent with the same compiler if `std::size_t` from `<cstddef>` is used across the source files?

Comment: Of course. But what if the library is compiled with a different compiler version? Or with a different multilib mode?  Or maybe it has a library that defines its own `size_t` as it sees fit (it has been seen)?

Comment: @rodrigo: Yes you are right about that! If that is the case, then it might get quite messy

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that the actual `size_t` typedef depends on several compiler options. Even in a full 32-bit machine, it can be `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` depending on the mood of the developers.

So, if the library is compiled with `typedef unsigned long size_t;` and your program is with `typedef unsigned int size_t;` you have a problem. You can check it with `objdump -t library | c++filt | grep AreaNodeIndex` or something like that.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this were the problem.  `size_t` is defined in the system includes, and should be the same everywhere.  Unless he's trying to link a 32-bit library with a file compiled in 64-bit mode, but in that case, I'd expect a lot more errors.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us the most important part: the command line used to
edit.  You're probably not specifying the library to be linked in
(options `-l` and `-L`, or you can specify the library as you would any
other file).

As for the linker specifying `unsigned int`, and the compiler `size_t`,
that's just an artifact of the way the errors are displayed: the
compiler will display the name of the `typedef` if that's what was used
when declaring the function.  The linker doesn't have this information,
so displays the name of the actual type.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're not linking with the library correctly.

Answer (score -1):

can you try

`const size_t cacheSize = 50000;`

instead?

[edit]
Well, I'd guess that if that declaration is giving you an unsigned long than there is some compiler option that's being overlooked, and that size_t is defined as a typedef over an unsigned long, in your compiler, and not a type that would match up with what the library see's.

Comment: That is semantically exactly the same as what he already has.