# Why is there a size_t defined in the global scope as well as in namespace std?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, size-t

I've noticed that my C++ programs compile fine whether I use `::size_t` or `std::size_t`.  I can use them interchangeably with no issues at all, so it seems like one of them is a `typedef` for the other.

As an example, consider the following code which uses the global `size_t` (this is the whole file, no `using`s and other stuff):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    ::size_t x = 100;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

The next code uses the `size_t` in `std`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::size_t x = 100;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Both compile fine and outputs `100` as expected.

I was under the impression that everything in the standard library is put in namespace `std`, but clearly this isn't the case.  Why is this so?

*Note: the same goes for `ptrdiff_t`, `intN_t` and `uintN_t` too.*

Comment: Maybe dupes, if not interesting reads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237370/does-stdsize-t-make-sense-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797279/what-to-do-with-size-t-vs-stdsize-t

Comment: @Tas Now I have another question.  If I remove `#include <iostream>` and add `#include <cstddef>`, `::size_t` will not be defined.  So it seems `#include <iostream>` internally does `#include <stddef.h>`, at least on GCC.

Comment: @Bernard, the C++ standard does not place a restriction on the additional headers included by any standard library header. So, that behavior of GCC isn't out of line with the standard

Comment: The duplicate is related but it doesn't seem to really answer this question

Comment: @WhiZTiM That comes as a surprise to me.  Many people say that as long as you don't do `using namespace std;` you'll be free from clashes with names in the standard library.

Answer (score -1):

According to what I've understood,`::size_t` and `std::size_t` are slightly different, but essentially the same, with a similar function.

There's a much better answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237370/does-stdsize-t-make-sense-in-c)

Hopes this helps!